# Squeak extensions of the system using HELP menu option

Tags: squeak

In squeak 4.3 if one follows the menu choices help/extending the system, one is faced with a window displaying text that is commenting some smalltalk expressions. It seems these expressions are aimed at "extending" the system. My questions are: (1) Are these extensions in sync and supported by Squeak or they are outdated? (2) Are they recommended? (3) Is there any order in which they should be executed?

Answer (score 0):

No, those extensions are mostly outdated. Try the 4.4 release, which is current.

http://ftp.squeak.org/4.4/Squeak4.4-12327.zip